# How to aggregate results grouped by custom intervals of time

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongo aggregation framework to aggregate sales between 2 dates and group them by `$dayOfYear`, `$week`, `$month` or `$year`.

I have a sales collection structured like this;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c23de50d2bdb749896e3f27"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-01-01T03:00:00.000Z"),
    "total" : 210000,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c23de52d2bdb749896e4f46"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-01-02T02:00:00.000Z"),
    "total" : 210000,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c23de52d2bdb749896e5039"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-01-02T03:00:00.000Z"),
    "total" : 210000,
}
...
...
```

I need the grouping to consider that each day starts from 3am and ends at 3am next day, for example; **2019-01-01 03:00:00** to **2019-01-02 03:00:00** should be a day.